# Sharepoint updating custom database

Tags: sharepoint, wss

Is it at all possible to leverage Sharepoint UI (e.g. lists editor), to perform basic CRUD operations on external database (owned and used by separate backend application)?
How would I go about this?

There are quite a few tables in this db, and I'm just looking to minimize custom code we'd need to develop and maintain (since we're not really a development shop - and dont have spare programmers lying around...).
(Preferably on WSS, and not MOSS... but willing to listen)

I should add this application is used internally, and these tables can be seen as complex configuration for backend processes - that need to change often, and also include data to "feed" the processes.

Moreover, I don't have interest in coding a custom WebPart for this, I might as well do a simple CRUD web app... I'm looking to leverage built-in functionality, and sufficing with configuration alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access data in another database and show it in the SharePoint UI without custom code, 3rd party products, or the BDC (part of MOSS Enterprise), then I recommend you look at the Data Form web part that can be added to a page using SharePoint Designer.  I'm sure there are many links out there on it - one that looked pretty good that I just found is [here](http://masteringsharepoint.com/blogs/beagle/archive/2008/08/13/DFWP1.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting - if a bit complicated. This does also allow editing the data, not just readonly view, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Or why not just do an asp.net application and not involve Sharepoint more than just view the page.....